# JSF Filter skip some files

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I have a project with this structure (I can't change it):

```
Web Pages
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
   assets (javascript, css and images)
   includes (top.xhtml, bottom.xhtml, etc)
   templates (master.xhtml)
   views
      fornecedor
         -home.xhtml
         -user.xhtml
         -login.xhtml
      franqueador
         -home.xhtml
         -user.xhtml
         -login.xhtml
```

O have a `login.xhtml` for each folder for a reason, I can't change it, it was passed by the project manager.

This is my SessionFilter:

```
@WebFilter("/views/*")
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        LoginController loginController = (LoginController) ((boolean) (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("loginController") : null);
        if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/fornecedor/index.xhtml")) {
            if (loginController == null || !loginController.getIsLoggedIn()) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()
                        + "/views/index.xhtml");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

And it doesn't work, returns a blank page with no html code and when I change the `.xhtml` to `.html`, it gives me a redirect loop.

I need to avoid all my `login.xhtml` pages and the `index.xhtml` on `views` folder. I have debugged the `if` on my filter but it always returns `false`.

**EDIT**

Following BalusC answer I came to this:

```
if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/views/index.html")
                && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/views/fornecedor/login.html")
                && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/views/franqueado/login.html")
                && (loginController == null || !loginController.getIsLoggedIn())) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/views/index.html");

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
```

It is working but there is another problem, if I have 10 folder, I'll need to add them on this `if` statement...I need to make it automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `if` condition has no `else`. That explains the blank page.

You need to evaluate the URL and logged-in conditions in a single `if` instead.

```
if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/fornecedor/index.xhtml") && (loginController == null || !loginController.getIsLoggedIn()) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/views/index.xhtml");
} else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

As to the redirect loop, that's because your `FacesServlet` is mapped on an URL pattern of `*.html` instead of `*.xhtml` for some unclear reason. So the request URL does never match. Fix the URLs in the filter accordingly. To generalize it for all `login.html` and `index.html` requests, just do as follows:

```
if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/index.html") 
    && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login.html") 
    && (loginController == null || !loginController.getIsLoggedIn())
{
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/views/index.html");
} else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but what about the `@WebFilter("/views/*")`? Just leave it this way?

Comment: This annotation registers the filter in the application and lets it run on URL patterns matching `/views/*`. If you remove this, the filter won't be registered at all and thus won't run at all.

Comment: but in my case I have some folders inside my `views` folder, the right choice is to leave it this way? `@WebFilter("/views/*")`

Comment: It will run on every URL pattern matching `/views/*` thus also `/views/someotherfolder/file.xhtml`. But, I've re-read your question once again and it seems like that you actually also have a `index.xhtml` in every folder (even though you didn't show it in the folder structure example) and that you'd like to treat `index.xhtml` the same way as `login.xhtml`. Is this true? It's also not clear what URL pattern your `FacesServlet` is mapped on. Is it `*.xhtml` or `*.html`? The checked request URL and the redirected URL in the filter must match exactly that URL pattern.

Comment: I don't have a `index.xhtml` on my folder, only on `views` and URL pattern is `html`

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're talking about `index.xhtml` in your question and why you're using `index.xhtml` in your filter. Anyway, you should be using `*.html` in your filter. I'll update the answer.

Comment: the `index.html` is the first page where I'll display some info and a link so the user can choose if he is a `fornecedor (folder)` or a `franqueador)folder` and inside those folders I have a `login.html`